# Dúvida com árvore binárias

Tags: c#, array

Tenho essa questão:
Escrever uma função que recebe uma árvore e um id e retorna um vetor com os ids do caminho desde o nó raiz até o nó passado como parâmetro.

```
int[] caminho_arvore(Arvore a, int n);
```

Exemplos:
Arvore a:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
caminho_arvore(a, 9) retorna  [1,4,2,12,13,9]
caminho_arvore(a,1) retorna [1]
caminho_arvore(a, 17) retorna []
caminho_arvore(a, 4) retorna [1,4]
```

A pergunta é uma só: Como eu faço para representar essa imagem(arvore) num array ou algo parecido. Apesar de haver muitos elementos na construção da pergunta, estão aí apenas para vocês entenderem, mas a resposta é uma só, como representar a imagem em C#.

Comment: Tens aqui uma implementação de uma árvore binária: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379572%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Representa-se uma arvore binaria em um array da seguinte forma: [pai, filho esquerda, filho direita, ...]. Mais precisamente, o indice do pai vale `(i - 1) / 2`, o do filho esquerdo `2*i + 1` e o do direito `2*i + 2`.

Comment: Parecido com o que precisa: http://www.introprogramming.info/tag/binary-search-trees/

Comment: @Alex, como eu representaria a imagem postada, num array conforme você está colocando. Ainda não consegui implementar.

Comment: pnet, conseguiu chegar a uma solução, se possível posta ai ..

Comment: Ainda não. Estou lendo bastante sobre o assunto.,

Answer (score 1):

Representa-se uma arvore binaria em um array da seguinte forma: [pai, filho esquerda, filho direita, ...]. Mais precisamente, o indice do pai vale `(i - 1) / 2`, o do filho esquerdo `2*i + 1` e o do direito `2*i + 2`.

Implementacao *quick and dirty*, assumindo uma AB (nao ABP) de numeros:

```
/* Retorna o indice do nodo na arvore, ou UINT_MAX se nao encontrado -- O(n) */ 
size_t                                                                          
index(int *tree, size_t nmemb, int node)                                        
{                                                                               
  size_t i = 0;                                                                 
  while (i < nmemb && tree[i] != node)                                          
    ++i;                                                                        
  return i < nmemb ? i : -1;                                                    
}                                                                               

int                                                                             
parent(int *tree, size_t nmemb, int node)                                       
{                                                                               
  size_t i = index(tree, nmemb, node);                                          
  if (i >= nmemb || !i)                                                         
    return INT_MAX;                                                             
  return tree[(i - 1) / 2];                                                     
}                                                                               

int                                                                             
left(int *tree, size_t nmemb, int node)                                         
{                                                                               
  size_t i = index(tree, nmemb, node);                                          
  size_t ans = 2*i + 1;                                                         
  if (i >= nmemb || ans >= nmemb)                                               
    return INT_MAX;                                                             
  return tree[ans];                                                             
}                                                                               

int                                                                             
right(int *tree, size_t nmemb, int node)                                        
{                                                                               
  size_t i = index(tree, nmemb, node);                                          
  size_t ans = 2*i + 2;                                                         
  if (i >= nmemb || ans >= nmemb)                                               
    return INT_MAX;                                                             
  return tree[ans];                                                             
}
```

E.g. http://pastebin.com/iGkk0UPq

```
debian@pc:~ ./a.out 2
Pai de 1: 2147483647 Esquerda: 2 Direita: 2147483647
Pai de 2: 1 Esquerda: 2147483647 Direita: 2147483647
debian@pc:~ ./a.out 3
Pai de 1: 2147483647 Esquerda: 2 Direita: 3
Pai de 2: 1 Esquerda: 2147483647 Direita: 2147483647
debian@pc:~ ./a.out 4
Pai de 1: 2147483647 Esquerda: 2 Direita: 3
Pai de 2: 1 Esquerda: 4 Direita: 2147483647
debian@pc:~ ./a.out 5
Pai de 1: 2147483647 Esquerda: 2 Direita: 3
Pai de 2: 1 Esquerda: 4 Direita: 5
```

Comment: Alex, quem é size_t? Não consegui entender essa parte do código.

Comment: @pnet `size_t` é um tipo inteiro positivo, e, como o nome indica, é usado para valores de "tamanho", índices, etc. Funções como `malloc` recebem-no como parâmetro. Por definição, é o tipo retornado por `sizeof`, e portanto suporta garantidamente pelo menos o índice máximo que uma array em memória virutal pode receber. Tanto a definição de `size_t` como a representação da arvore em array podem ser facilmente encontrados com uma busca no Google. Procure utiliza-lo mais antes de perguntar.